# Dynamic value from shell script output in Paw

Tags: paw-app

Is there a way to create a dynamic value that executes a shell script and takes the stdout from it? I'm working with a header that changes every couple of minutes, and for the moment I have to manually execute the script, copy the output and insert it into my environment variables. This is tedious to do it so often... I managed to make my own extension for dynamic value, but I couldn't find a way to execute local scripts and return the string. Ist this even possible? Or are any other possibilities to do this?

Comment: Unfortunatey, not yet. We've thought about adding this possibility, but we haven't decided yet whether we'll implement this. In fact, Paw has a JavaScript API (see "API Reference" in https://paw.cloud/docs/) and this may solve most of user needs. Though, we're of course open to new ideas :)

Comment: OK, pity. Now I'm using a file, and execute the script manually and let paw read from the file. I saw the JS api, and started doing my own extension with it, but got stuck when I had to execute a local script on my machine. Would be cool if this would be possible, or at least provide a method over the JS api for this...? I know there could be some security issues... but still, could be very useful. :)